# Get projects from Teamweek in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get the planning from [Teamweek](https://teamweek.com) in my js app. ([API](https://github.com/toggl/teamweek_api_docs))

```
function get_teamweek_planning()
{
    var api_url     = 'https://teamweek.com/api/v2/',
        api_key     = '1234567',
        object_type = 'projects';

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: api_url + api_key + '/projects.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        data: {},

        success:function(response){
            console.log('response:', response);
        }
    });     
}
```

This returns a 403 (forbidden). This is [documented](https://github.com/toggl/teamweek_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/authentication.md) and means authentication fails. But how do i fix it?

Comment: Not sure from their documentation example using curl, but try adding `auth_token` in data: `data: {auth_token: your_token_here}` and if that  fails perhaps try the same in the ajax headers key, something like `headers: {"Authorization": "auth_token " + your_token_here}`

Comment: Those don't work... tried them all:
    function get_teamweek_planning()
{
var api_url = 'https://teamweek.com/api/v2/', api_key= '1234567'; 
$.ajax({
url:api_url + api_key + '/projects.json',
type:'GET',
dataType:'jsonp',
cache:false,
/*data:{auth_token: api_key}, */
/*headers:{"Authorization": "auth_token " + api_key}, */
/*beforeSend:function(req) { req.setRequestHeader('auth_token', api_key);}, */
success:function(response){ console.log(response);},
error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.error('error getting teamweek planning:', jqXHR);}});  
}

Comment: Nobody can read that, here's a pen: http://codepen.io/mettin/pen/Garko

Comment: Are you sure you are using the token and not the user id? From their docs: `The token can be found on a users profile page.`

Comment: Yes. A nice weird string...

Comment: Just tried it myself with a free account. Their API is borken. It actually lets you log in via the token as a URL parameter, and I can get it to distinguish between a good and bad token. I'd email their support.

Comment: Okay thanks @Pathétique! I've tried twitter support but they're not real helpfull so far (in all fairness, it's only been 2 days): https://twitter.com/TeamWeekPlan/status/393351602704506880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function get_teamweek_planning()
{
    var api_url     = 'https://teamweek.com/api/v2/',
        account_id  = '<your account id>';

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: api_url + account_id + '/projects.json',
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
         request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + btoa('<your api token>'))
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        data: {},

        success:function(response){
            console.log('response:', response);
        }
    });     
}
```

If your're using this on a page that isn't only for yourself then do not hard code your token...

Comment: Thanks this worked! The problem is that the API is unclear what i should enter as account_id and api token. I provided the account_id and public_view_token which can be found as a data attribute on the body when logged in to Teamweek.

Comment: Any idea on how to get tasks for 1 user?

Comment: No such limitations as of this time... Current way is something like getting the tasks and then filtering out needed ones. You could use underscore's _.filter() for that.
Also, you might try opening an issue on the teamweek api docs repo at github, it might get implemented :)

Comment: Filtering the array in JS isn't the problem. Efficiency is =) Any idea on how to get a error/callback from a jsonp call when the user presses 'cancel' when prompted for their teamweek user/pass? I'll do just that!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the authentication part, you need to authenticate on every request (as is documented on github).

Include the following vars for in the data object:

```
data: {
    auth_token: [your token],
    name: [client name]
}
```

https://github.com/toggl/teamweek_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/authentication.md

Comment: name is for when you want to create a client... i just want to fetch data. My auth_token seems to fail.

Comment: Can't you renew or check your auth token somewhere in a console of some sort?

Comment: Nope.. not in their user page