# Create new project with teamweek api in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

After getting the planning ([Get projects from Teamweek in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565558/get-projects-from-teamweek-in-jquery)) successfully via the API i now want to create feed teamweek a project.

The following code works (according to the response i get) but i can't find the project when i log in to teamweek.

[Teamweek API Documentation](https://github.com/toggl/teamweek_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/projects.md)

```
create_project = function(_project)
{
    console.log('Sending new project to teamweek', _project);
    return $.ajax(
    {
        url         : api_url + app.model.teamweek_account_id + '/projects/new.json',
        type        : 'POST',
        dataType    : 'jsonp',
        cache       : false,
        data        : {
                             "active"       : true,
                             "client_id"    : _project.client,
                             "color"        : "#f00",
                             "name"         : _project.title,
                             "id"           : _project.project_number
                      },

        beforeSend: function (request) { return request; },

        success:function(response) {
            return response;
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('error getting teamweek planning:', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
    }); 
},
```

Response:

```
{
    "project": {
        "name": "text",
        "client_id": "integer",
        "color": "string",
        "active": "boolean"
    },
    "links": [{
        "href": "https://teamweek.com/api/v2/:my_account_id/projects",
        "rel": "create",
        "method": "POST"
    }, {
        "href": "https://teamweek.com/api/v2/:my_account_id/projects/:id",
        "rel": "update",
        "method": "PUT"
    }, {
        "href": "https://teamweek.com/api/v2/:my_account_id/projects/:id",
        "rel": "read",
        "method": "GET"
    }, {
        "href": "https://teamweek.com/api/v2/:my_account_id/projects/:id",
        "rel": "delete",
        "method": "DELETE"
    }, {
        "href": "https://teamweek.com/api/v2/:my_account_id/projects",
        "rel": "list",
        "method": "GET"
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint is incorrect, from the API docs (https://github.com/toggl/teamweek_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/projects.md#create-project)

POST https://teamweek.com/api/v2/:account_id/projects.json

Your response should be the created project, not the template...

Comment: Are you sending a POST request? GET /projects returns the project list...
It looks like you're doing exactly that.
Use POST, also, you might try using pure json, not jsonp

Comment: POST. pure json gives a cross-domain error...
I've put my code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mettin/4U8WH/1/

Comment: Well, it seems using JSONP is your culprit. From this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699277/post-data-to-jsonp (hence, you cannot do a POST request with JSONP).
If you want to build an interface inside a browser and doing direct requests, then either forget about POST/DELETE/PUT request (get only, just display data) or add a some sort of middle plate to do the requests for you.
If this doesn't suit your ideas, well, contact support@teamweek.com about getting an exception for your project in CORS headers (why, where etc)...